# Get method : form input not in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, url

I am doing my first ASP.NET mvc project, on the home page, Index.cshtml, I have a small form:

```
<form action="ChoixFormulaire" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label>NAS</label>
        <input id="nas" type="text" placeholder="###"/>
        <br />
        <label>Date of birth</label>
        <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="AAAA-MM-JJ"/>
        <br />
        <label>Employee number</label>
        <input id="numEmployee" type="text" placeholder="######"/>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Soumettre" onclick="return VerifierFormulaire()" />
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, there is some verification made in the 'VerifierFormulaire()' method, which is defined in the same Index.cshtml file. Then the ChoixFormulaire.cshtml is displayed (called from the ChoixFormulaire() method in my HomeController, which returns View()).

I was expecting the form inputs to be in the URL as parameters. For example, If I enter '123' for NAS, '1989-01-01' for date of birth and '123456' for employee number, I am redirected to http://localhost:15778/Home/ChoixFormulaire? but I would expect to be redirected to http://localhost:15778/Home/ChoixFormulaire?nas=123&dateBirth=1989-01-01&numEmployee=123456

Comment: Try changing your form method to "post"

Comment: But I thought the get method would put the parameters in the url... I am not planning on adding/changing any data, that's why I don't want to use the 'post' method. Just try the post by curiosity and I still don't have the parameters in the url (which is normal I think for a post method).

Comment: What does your VerifierFormulaire() function look like?

Comment: The problem was the name attribute missing.. I thought I had to use the id

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the name attribute:

```
<input id="nas" name="nas" />
```

Comment: Try taking out your onclick event after adding the name attribute and make sure that something in the verification is not clearing the values.  I tried your form locally to verify and with the id only I did not get anything in the url, but after adding the name I did.